# Need help loading simple text data with c++

Tags: c++, file-io, codeblocks

I need help loading a custom file format into my program made in c++...
I know there's a simple way of doing this but I think I'm using the
wrong terms to search for it online...

My custom format for 3d objects is as follows:

```
NumVerts 6
//verts (float)
-1
-1
0
1
-1
0
-1
1
0
1
-1
0
1
1
0
-1
1
0
//texture (float)
0
0
1
0
0
1
1
0
1
1
0
1
//index (int)
0
1
2
1
3
2
```

And that is a quad... (yeas; I know... horrible format... but it's what I'm using for an android game).

I want to make a function in c++ for my editor (SDL + OpenGL for windows) that loads these files into data... Unfortunately though I know how to export this format with C++, I can't figure out how to import them... I wish to use the fstream commands...

If someone could quickly write out a simple version I'd be really thankful.

I just it to do the following:

- Find text file from input string
- read "NumVerts" and grab the integer written after it
- loop through the next (NumVerts*3) lines and grab each number as a float
- loop though the next (NumVerts*2) lines and grab each number as a float
- loop through the next (NumVerts*1) lines and grab each number as an Int
- (skip any line that starts with "//")
- close file.

Thank you for reading and any help would be really good right now... or a relivent link that is quite simple and reads strings from files and grabs numbers from them to be placed into memory...

I really just want to finish this game and it's getting really stressful trying to locate helpful tutorials.

Update: updated the script... I accidently forgot to seperate 1's and 0's...

Comment: If this is a serious project, you should consider a more efficient binary format (maybe like NetCDF).

Comment: @KerrekSB Regarding "serious projects", I am a bit reluctant of using binary formats, as they are not necessarily portable (endianess, floating point format). For instance, COLLADA is pretty "serious" and still stores vertices as strings.

Comment: @zerm: Something self-descriptive like NetCDF is designed with portability in mind... anyway, serialization portability is just a measure of the author's ability to document the format!

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't know if it's what would be called a "serious project", it's just a really simple 3d engine for Android phones... this is really my first test... might try and sell a game or two, but it's really just a learning tool for myself... Thanks for the tip though... never heard of NetCDF actually... I shall research.

Comment: @zerm: I think you both have pretty good points, plus a file format should suite what the user is comfortable with... I'll probably move into something more binary based later, but I'm okay with more simple stuff right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps. Incidentally, you have the wrong number of vertex components - you need `18` of them.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
using boost::lexical_cast;

int load_3d_object(const std::string& filename,
                   std::vector<float>& vertComponents,
                   std::vector<float>& texComponents,
                   std::vector<int>& indices)
{
    std::ifstream fs(filename.c_str());
    std::string line;
    if(!std::getline(fs, line))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("The input file is empty");
    }

    if(line.substr(0,8) != "NumVerts")
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("The first line must start with NumVerts");
    }

    // Extract the number of vertices.
    int numVerts = lexical_cast<int>(line.substr(line.find(' ') + 1));

    // Read in the vertex components, texture components and indices.
    while(std::getline(fs, line))
    {
        boost::trim(line);
        if(line.substr(0,2) == "//") continue;

        if((int)vertComponents.size() < numVerts * 3)       vertComponents.push_back(lexical_cast<float>(line));
        else if((int)texComponents.size() < numVerts * 2)   texComponents.push_back(lexical_cast<float>(line));
        else                                                indices.push_back(lexical_cast<int>(line));
    }

    return numVerts;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> vertComponents;
    std::vector<float> texComponents;
    std::vector<int> indices;
    try
    {
        int numVerts = load_3d_object("input.txt", vertComponents, texComponents, indices);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am I just overlooking this, or did you miss handling comments correctly? You should add something like `if(line.find("//")!=0) lines.push_back(line);`

Comment: @zerm: In the second version I'm just skipping lines which start with // (which is fine because I trimmed them earlier). I'm not claiming that this is how I'd write it for production code - it's definitely not. The first version accounts for the comment lines by assuming that the file format is per the example - and setting the start indices accordingly.

Comment: @Stuart Golodetz: Thank you for pointing out the fact there wasn't 18 variables... I sort of just typed it out quickly and didn't think to double check...
(I'm sort of tired). I'll see if I can write something based off your code... Thanks alot; looks exactly like what I need. Thanks for explaining the code to me.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz: I looked through the code again just before I was going to start incorperating it, but then I realised that I've never seen "boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp" or the "lexical cast"... I tried scanning my codeblocks folder and entire computer for "trim.hpp", but couldn't find it... Do I have to get this from somewhere inparticular?

Comment: @Kalisme: Both of those are from header-only libraries, so you don't need to compile any libraries or anything like that - just download Boost and set the include path correctly.

Comment: If you don't want to use Boost for some reason, it wouldn't be too hard to implement either of those things - for `lexical_cast`, see e.g. https://sites.google.com/site/dustingetz/dev-etc/naive-lexical_cast-impl-without-boost

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this might help (minimal error checking):

```
int _get_num_verts_value(std::ifstream& a_in)
{
    char buf[128];
    int result = -1;
    a_in.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    while (a_in.good())
    {
        if (a_in.gcount() > 9)
        {
            string s(buf);
            if (0 == s.find("NumVerts "))
            {
                result = atoi(s.substr(8).c_str());
                break;
            }
        }
        a_in.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
void _get_values(std::ifstream& a_in, std::vector<T>& a_values)
{
    char buf[128];
    a_in.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    int i = 0;
    while (a_in.good())
    {
        string line(buf);
        if (0 != line.find("//"))
        {
            a_values[i++] = boost::lexical_cast<T>(line);
            // All read ?
            if (i == a_values.capacity())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        a_in.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
}

int main(int /*a_argc*/, char** /*a_argv*/)
{
    ifstream in("test.txt");
    const int num_verts_value = _get_num_verts_value(in);

    std::vector<float> verts(num_verts_value * 3);
    _get_values<float>(in, verts);

    std::vector<float> textures(num_verts_value * 2);
    _get_values<float>(in, textures);

    std::vector<int> indexes(num_verts_value);
    _get_values<int>(in, indexes);

    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `getline` into a fixed-size buffer when `std::getline` will allow you to read straight into a `std::string`? :)

Comment: @Stuart, are you sure? Just rechecked doc and no `getline()` takes a `std::string` and I just tried it in VC10 and got compilation failure.

Comment: @stuart, you are correct. I thought you were referring to `ifstream::getline()`. Using `std::getline()` here would be better, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using a flat file for this purpose could be a bad idea. it's pretty fragile. I prefer to a binary file or a self-described file (e.g xml).

```
std::ifstream in("in");
char buf[256];
std::string line;
int NumVerts;
in >> buf >> NumVerts;
std::vector<float> verts(NumVerts * 3);
std::getline(in, line);//read the rest of the line
std::getline(in, line);//skip the comment line
std::for_each(verts.begin(), verts.end(), [&in](float& par){
    in >> par;
});
std::vector<float> texture(NumVerts * 2);
std::getline(in, line);//read the rest of the line
std::getline(in, line);//skip the comment line
std::for_each(texture.begin(), texture.end(), [&in](float& par){
    in >> par;
});
std::vector<int> index(NumVerts);
std::getline(in, line);//read the rest of the line
std::getline(in, line);//skip the comment line
std::for_each(index.begin(), index.end(), [&in](int& par){
    in >> par;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the links on how to DIY:

- Tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/
- Reference: http://new.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/

Example code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> // needed for printing stuff out
#include <fstream>  // Needed to read the file
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Vertice {
    double x,y,z; // 3 part stuff to read
    double a,b;   // 2 part stuff to read
    int i;        // 1 int thing to read
};

/// Reads a number ignoring comment lines (and any other line that isn't a number)
template <typename T>
T readNumber(istream& data) {
    char lastChar;
    while (data.good()) {
        data >> lastChar; // Don't use peek as that won't skip whitespace
        data.putback(lastChar);
        if (( (lastChar >= '0') && (lastChar <= '9') ) || (lastChar == '-')) {
            // If we're looking at a number read and return it
            T result;
            data >> result;
            return result;
        } else {
            // If it's not part of a number .. assume it's a comment line and skip the whole line
            string commentLine;
            getline(data, commentLine);
            // TODO: Maybe just skip '//' lines and throw an exception for everything else..
        }
    }
    throw exception("Couldn't read file");
}

double readDouble(istream& data) { return readNumber<double>(data); }
int readInt(istream& data) { return readNumber<int>(data); }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) 
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [DATA_FILE_NAME]" << endl;
    else {
        fstream data(argv[1], ios_base::in);
        data >> skipws; // Skip whitespace
        string lastString;
        long numVerts = -1;
        // Read in words ignoring everything until we hit a 'NumVerts'
        while (numVerts < 0) {
            data >> lastString;
            if (lastString == "NumVerts")
                data >> numVerts;
        }
        // We know how many to get now
        typedef vector<Vertice> Verts;
        Verts verts(numVerts);
        // Read in the triples
        for (Verts::iterator i=verts.begin(); i != verts.end(); ++i) {
            i->x = readDouble(data);
            i->y = readDouble(data);
            i->z = readDouble(data);
        }
        // Read in the pairs (some other data)
        for (Verts::iterator i=verts.begin(); i != verts.end(); ++i) {
            i->a = readDouble(data);
            i->b = readDouble(data);
        }
        // Read in the single integer value
        for (Verts::iterator i=verts.begin(); i != verts.end(); ++i) {
            i->i = readInt(data);
        }
        // Print out all we found
        for (Verts::iterator i=verts.begin(); i != verts.end(); ++i) {
            cout << "Vertice" << endl
                 << "  x: " << i->x << endl
                 << "  y: " << i->y << endl
                 << "  z: " << i->z << endl
                 << "  a: " << i->a << endl
                 << "  b: " << i->b << endl
                 << "  i: " << i->i << endl
                 << endl;
        }

    }

}
```

The example code throws an error on the provided files as there isn't enough data to fill out the 'NumVerts'.